# Return first value that exceeds 0.8 within groups

Tags: r, dataframe, percentile

```
data<-data.frame(c(A,A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C),c(0.2,0.78,0.82,0,1,0.1,0.81,1,0.8,0.92,1))
```

I would like to choose only first 80% within each group (A,B). Means I cannot use ordinary <. Any ideas?

Comment: Your arguments for the `data.frame()` function have not the same length. Hence, the example does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

data <-
  data.table(
    "GroupID"  = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
    "Value" = c(0.2, 0.78, 0.82, 0, 1, 0.1, 0.81, 1, 0.8, 0.92, 1)
  )

data[, head(Value, n = floor(nrow(.SD) * 0.8)), by = GroupID]
```

Choose between `floor` and `ceiling` (or `round`) based on how you want to round number of observations to 80%. (What is the 80% of 3 observations? 2 or 3)

Change `0.8` to control for percentage.

`head` for the first 80% or `tail` for the last 80%.

Output:

```
      GroupID   V1
1:       A 0.20
2:       A 0.78
3:       A 0.82
4:       B 1.00
5:       B 0.10
6:       C 1.00
7:       C 0.80
8:       C 0.92
```

**Edit**:
I just realised that your title and body text seems to mean two different questions.

Here is the answer for the title question:

```
data[Value > 0.8, first(Value), by = GroupID]
```

Output:

```
  GroupID   V1
1:       A 0.82
2:       B 1.00
3:       C 1.00
```